# TrueCrypts full Disk Encryption still secure?

Tags: hash, truecrypt, nsa

I'm wondering because it only uses RIMPEMD-160 with just 3000 iterations. Isn't that somewhat low and weak?

Even though I saw the NSA document that the NSA were not able to break TrueCrypt in 2012.

Answer (score -1):

even if they were not able to decrypt in 2012, that doesn't mean that the NSA will take the locked door entrance when they already have a backdoor open, seeing as  they are known for having backdoor in many OS distributions, as well as being able to decrypt HTTPS. these documents are also from 2012, and truecrypt has stopped support for almost a year now, so we have to assume that by now the NSA is able to decrypt it.

sources:
http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/ 
http://www.theverge.com/2014/12/28/7458159/encryption-standards-the-nsa-cant-crack-pgp-tor-otr-snowden

Comment: Your answer is all opinion, no fact and is not even backed up by sound logic. -1

Comment: @mikeazo, i am unable to put more sources of where i got my information from :'( , here is the other, and btw all the info is from the sources, including the one about NSA being able to decrypt Full disk encryption.
http://www.commondreams.org/news/2014/07/23/apple-denies-it-built-nsa-backdoor-600-million-devices